# ElasticSearch nested AGGS plus AND / OR filtering logs

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, filtering

I'm indexing some logs into ElasticSearch and I've some doubts asking ES API in order to get some information...

I've an index with this mapping:

```
"appName" : {
"type" : "string",
    "index" : "not_analyzed"
},  
"log" : {
    "type" : "string"
},  
"projectName" : {
    "type" : "string",
    "index" : "not_analyzed"
}
```

I've some projects ("projectName") with some applications ("appName") 'inside'. Example: App1 and App2 belongs to Project1.
"log" is for the 'log line', that came from applications stdout/stderror.

I'm able to get the latest hour log lines containing for example 'debug' in the log line... using aggs and getting the info in buckets. I'm doing it this way (curl query to the ES api):

```
{
 "size" : 0,
 "query" :
 { "range" : { "time" : { "from" : "now-1h", "to" : "now" } } },
 "aggs":
 {
  "matcheo"  :
  {
   "filter": 
   {
    "match": { "log" : "debug" }
   },   
   "aggs":
   {
    "projectName":
    {    
     "terms": { "field": "projectName", "size":0 },
     "aggs":
     {
      "appName":
      {
       "terms": { "field": "appName", "size":0 }
      } 
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Result:

```
...
    "matcheo" : {
      "doc_count" : 25,
      "projectName" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [ {
          "key" : "Project1",
          "doc_count" : 12,
          "appName" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [ {
              "key" : "App1",
              "doc_count" : 12
             }, {
              "key" : "App2",
              "doc_count" : 48
            },              
           } ]
...
```

an so on with each appName in each projectName... I got that Project1 has two apps: App1 with 12 docs containing "debug" and App2 with 48 docs containing "debug"...

What I'm trying to do right now and I'm not able, is to get the latest hour log lines containing 'debug' or 'error' or 'warning' but 'aggreged' by this terms. For example to get for each appName (in each projectName) how many "log:" contains "debug", how many "log:" contains "error" and how many "log:" contains "warning"...

I've tried to 'filter' match with: `"match": { "log" : "debug warning error" }` and I don't get how many for each 'term'.

Is anyone able to help me please? Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! With Filters Aggregations!

```
{
 "size" : 0, 
 "query" :
 { "range" : { "time" : { "from" : "now-1h", "to" : "now" } } },
 "aggs":
 {    
  "projectName":
  {    
   "terms": { "field": "projectName", "size": 0},
   "aggs":
   { 
    "appName":
    {
     "terms": { "field": "appName", "size": 0},
     "aggs":
     {
      "typology" :
      {
       "filters" :
       {
        "other_bucket_key": "other",
        "filters" :
        {
         "errors" :   { "match" : { "log" : "error"   }},
         "warnings" : { "match" : { "log" : "warning" }},
         "debug" : { "match" : { "log" : "debug" }}
        }
       }
      } 
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

So it works and now I'm able to get something like this:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "projectName" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "Project1",
        "doc_count" : 5,
        "appName" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [ {
            "key" : "App1",
            "doc_count" : 5,
            "tipologia" : {
              "buckets" : {
                "errors" : {
                  "doc_count" : 0
                },
                "warnings" : {
                  "doc_count" : 0
                },
                "debug" : {
                  "doc_count" : 5
                },
                "other" : {
                  "doc_count" : 0
                }
              }
            }
          }, {
          "key" : "App2",
            "doc_count" : 4,
            "tipologia" : {
              "buckets" : {
                "errors" : {
                  "doc_count" : 2
                },
                "warnings" : {
                  "doc_count" : 0
                },
                "debug" : {
                  "doc_count" : 2
                },
                "other" : {
                  "doc_count" : 0
                }
              }
            }
          } ]
        }
      }
```

I think I'm using best method to get this... am I?

Regards.